# How to stop repeated data using sql query in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

I am create a stored procedure in SQL Server for showing feed with also feed comment but I am creating this stored procedure using repeated data also show here below I have listed my table with data any one please help me how can show my satisfaction data using SQL Server.

**Feed** table :

```
    FeedID | userId  | Caption | TotalComments | InsertDateTime

    1         101          Test        3              2017-05-04 18:51:23.960
    2         102          Party       2              2017-05-03 17:51:23.960
    3         103          event       3              2017-05-02 18:10:23.960
```

**FeedComment** table :

```
    FeedCommentID | FeedID | UserId | Comment | InsertDateTime

    1                  1      102      Good          2017-05-04 18:51:23.960
    2                  1      103      Bad           2017-05-04 16:51:23.960
    3                  2      102      Very Good     2017-05-04 18:51:23.960
    4                  1      101      ....          2017-05-04 14:51:23.960
```

Expected output:

```
    FeedID | userId  | Caption | TotalComments | InsertDateTime

    1         101          Test        3              2017-05-04 18:51:23.960
    2         102          Party       2              2017-05-03 17:51:23.960
    3         103          event       3              2017-05-02 18:10:23.960
```

With my query, I get this output:

```
    FeedID | userId  | Caption | TotalComments | InsertDateTime

    1         101          Test        3              2017-05-04 18:51:23.960
    1         101          Test        3              2017-05-04 18:51:23.960  
    1         101          Test        3              2017-05-04 18:51:23.960
    2         102          Party       2              2017-05-03 17:51:23.960
    3         103          event       3              2017-05-02 18:10:23.960
```

Here this is my table and data and below I have written this query but it does not return proper data :

```
SELECT 
    C.FeedID, *,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM FeedComment 
     WHERE FeedID = C.FeedID ) AS TotalComments
FROM 
    Feed C
INNER JOIN 
    Users U ON C.UserId = U.UserId
-- here I use a left join that's not returning proper data; 
-- without this left join proer data is returned, but I want to 
-- write this join so any one know how can manage 
LEFT JOIN
    FeedComment CC ON CC.FeedID = C.FeedID  
ORDER BY 
    CC.InsertDateTime DESC  
    OFFSET (1- 1) * 20 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Why you need to join FeedComment ? , this is the reason for repeatation.

Comment: yes but i want who feed get new comment it's come on the top feed that's  i am write this join

Comment: @SHD any idea abut this how can manage this query with join please help me on that

Comment: yes, I will update the code, just a minute

Comment: ok thanks i am waiting for answer np

Comment: which table belogs to inserteddatetime to display ?

Comment: FeedComment table

Comment: do u only need last date to display ?

Comment: yes i need that

Comment: please check the query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143460/discussion-between-coderwill-and-shd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query,

```
SELECT C.FeedID,userId,MAX(CC.CaptionInsertDateTime) AS CaptionInsertDateTime,                 
           COUNT(*) AS TotalComments
    FROM Feed C
    INNER JOIN Users U ON C.UserId = U.UserId
    LEFT join FeedComment CC ON CC.FeedID = C.FeedID 
    GROUP BY C.FeedID,userId
    ORDER BY MAX(CC.InsertDateTime) DESC  OFFSET (1- 1) * 20 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

or

```
SELECT C.FeedID,*                 
       ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FeedComment WHERE FeedID = C.FeedID ) AS TotalComments
       ,(SELECT MAX(InsertDateTime) FROM FeedComment CC WHERE CC.FeedID = C.FeedID) AS InsertDateTime
FROM Feed C
INNER JOIN Users U ON C.UserId = U.UserId
ORDER BY InsertDateTime DESC  OFFSET (1- 1) * 20 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: hello can you please reply me.

Comment: hello i am asking on chat

Comment: this query using ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY order by) possible? with out group by

Comment: Hy @SHD can you please help me one in sql server ?

Comment: Yes, please ask

Comment: i have the 2 table in our db 1st is feed and 2nd is feedcomment so i want to daily on feed who's give comment want to this count daily in last 7 days count and my expected out put is like this =>

Comment: DateColumn | Count
09-05-2017    10
08-05-2017    05
07-05-2017    20
06-05-2017    10
05-05-2017    30
04-05-2017    50
03-05-2017    40

Comment: Please ask it as new question, with expected output

Comment: ok i will asking new question and after give the comment here so that time you can please help me i will give the here link also ok please

Comment: Hello @SHD i am ask the one question for sql server please can you please help me?

Comment: Okay, Please ask

Comment: i am ask one new question on stack overflow please you can see this is my question number "43890806".

Comment: Okay, I will post answer.

Comment: yes worked acatully it's my mistke in the query i was wrong UserFollowers id take it it's pk so i replace this to Followresid in inner join so now worked thanks

Comment: Hello @SHD can i ask one question?

Comment: I Want to also updatedatetime desc feed and then after who feed get a comment he comes on the top and this updatedatetime comes after letes comment feed can you please help

Comment: please ask in detail, I did't get it.

Comment: Please see this post This is id for the post "43908405"

Comment: have you got this post?

Comment: any idea how can fix ti that query?

Comment: have you check my post have you any idea how can do that?please give me any updates

Comment: hello can you please reply me

Comment: can i add some case cnd in order by with updatedatetime and insertdatetime between it's correct wave?

Comment: Hello can you please help me on this my post no "44300777"

Comment: hello can you please give a replay